# angularjs: how to make ng-model dynamic in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i m using blueimp jquery file upload (angular version)

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="file in queue" data-ng-class="{'processing': file.$processing()}">
    <td data-ng-controller="MyController">                   
      <p >     
       <span  ng-click="clickme()" ng-show="edit==false" >{{file.name}} </span>                   
     <input type="text" class='form-control filenameinput'  value="{{file.name}}" ng-show="edit==true>
</p></td>
```

i wanted to provide inline editing. so when user will click on span i will hide span and show text box with file name and on blur i will show span again with modified file name.

MyController

```
$scope.edit = false;

            $scope.clickme = function () {
                $scope.edit = true;
            }
```

issue is that file.name is not a ng-model so if user make changes in text box that doesn't appear in span

how can i make {{file.name}} to be ng-model 
is it possible ? 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Declare file as object in your controller like $scope.file = {}; Then you can add properties to it.

Comment: You should also set input attribute ng-model='file.name'

Comment: Nevermind my first comment. It was brain fart.

Comment: Um, how about `<input ng-model="file.name" />`?

Comment: it didnt work.  <p data-ng-controller="MyController" class="name" >                     
                        <span  ng-click="clickme()" ng-show="edit==false" >{{file.name}}</span>
                        <input type="text" class='form-control filenameinput' ng-show="edit==true"  ng-model="file.name">
                    </p>